# vRealize getting java.lang error when I try to run an action

Tags: javascript, vcenter

I am getting an error when I run my action and workflow. When I check my log this is the error I am getting.
Cannot convert "hostname" to java.lang.Object[] (Dynamic Script Module name : myWorkFlow#82)
When I look at line 82 I am trying to get all the vms from vCenter

```
var allVms = VcPlugin.getAllVirtualMachines(inputs['newName']);
```

inputs['newName'] just gets me the hostname that I created. But I am not sure what I am doing wrong to move forward.

Comment: `VcPlugin.getAllVirtualMachines()` accetps two arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can find all vms from the VcPlugin, simply with this code:

```
var allVms = VcPlugin.getAllVirtualMachines([], "");
var hostFqdn = "<your-host-fqdn-here>";
var vmsForHost = allVms.filter(function(vm) {
    return vm.parent.name === hostFqdn;
});

//check: print out the vms names
vmsForHost.forEach(function(vm) {
    System.log('vm name = '+vm.name);
})
```

HTH :)